# Reading values of AverageRating & Number of Ratings in code behind of application page in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, rating

I'm working on rating feature for our SharePoint application. I have a custom list something like below:
ex.

UserId -- Title -- JobId -- Rating(0-5) -- Number of Ratings

UserId & JobId together makes unique key.

Basically, I have to read rating values and create aggregate and display in UI. 
So, in my application page I need to read these 'Rating' & 'Number of Ratings' field values.

Can any one please suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the rating for [list item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx) use the following method:

```
public SocialRating GetRating(
    Uri url
)
```

exposed by class [SocialRatingManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee583363.aspx)

To construct [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) for the [list item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx) the following code could be used:

```
var itemUrl = new Uri(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.Url, item.Url));
```

---

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve Social Ratings for list item:

```
private static SocialRating GetListItemSocialRatings(SPWeb web, SPListItem item)
{
    var context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(web.Site);
    var socialRatingManager = new SocialRatingManager(context);

    var itemUrl = new Uri(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.Url, item.Url));
    return socialRatingManager.GetRating(itemUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have URI of the item, it's easy to read rating for a list item. Check the link below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407954.aspx

And

[SocialRatingManager Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.socialdata.socialratingmanager_members.aspx)

Comment: This one is good. Could you suggest me how to find/get the uri for items in a custom list.